# Prevent addition of a BOM to UTF-8 SecureCRT session logged files

Tags: utf-8, byte, byte-order-mark

SecureCRT appears to be adding a BOM to all session logged files no matter what character encoding is selected.  When UTF-8 is used, SecureCRT generates a UTF-8 with BOM file rather than a simple UTF-8 file.

The reason the BOM is a problem is that I have to open all of my files in Word, and because there is a BOM Word makes me choose what encoding I want every time I try and open a file.  I can see the BOM if I choose any encoding besides UTF-8.  It isn't that big of a deal if only opening one or two files, but I'm creating and opening hundreds of files.  If I open the session logged file into Notepad, then choose "Save As" I can see that SecureCRT saved it as UTF-8 with BOM.  If I change it to just UTF-8, then save it, I can then open it in Word without the extra pop-up asking what encoding I want to use.  Opening in Notepad and Saving as UTF-8 only just to open it in Word is obviously more steps than just opening in Word and choosing the encoding.

Any insight on how to prevent SecureCRT from adding the blasted BOM would be greatly appreciated.  I'm on Windows 10 using SecureCRT version 9.3.1.  Thank you!

I've looked all over the internet and SecureCRT help files and I can't seem to find an answer to this question.  I've tried multiple different character encoding options, but can't seem to get SecureCRT to not add a BOM to the UTF-8 encoded files.  I've also played with a couple settings in the default.ini and session.ini files but to no avail (not sure what I'm doing in there to be honest).  I didn't see anything that looked promising in the global.ini files, but I really don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question, If you're asking about how to use some software, you may be able to ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: I ended up finding this thread on MrExcel as I'm using VBA as part of this project: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convert-text-file-to-true-utf-8-not-utf-16-be-bom.1187935/page-2. I was able to use Domenic's code in that thread to simply loop through all my session logged files and take off the BOM characters.  Worked like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding this thread on MrExcel as I'm using VBA as part of this project: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convert-text-file-to-true-utf-8-not-utf-16-be-bom.1187935/page-2. I was able to use Domenic's code in that thread to simply loop through all my session logged files and take off the BOM characters.  Worked like a dream.  That way I didn't have to worry about trying to get SecureCRT to not add the BOM.  Thanks to all those who took at look at this.